# Android: how to have select effect "selectableItemBackground" on ImageView with round icon drawable?

Tags: android

Currently, when I click on this button I have this effect:

[image]

The "button" is just the ImageView like that:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_link"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"              
            android:src="@drawable/ic_added" />
```

So my question is: how can I do to have not a square selection but a **round selection** on this ImageView (doesn't matter the view type) with *selectableItemBackground* effect, something like that:

[image]

Comment: use this https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView

Comment: http://michaelevans.org/blog/2015/05/07/android-ripples-with-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 5):

You should use as background:

```
background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Comment: That's only available on API 21 and did not seem to work on an ImageView.

Comment: Im pretty sure this is available in previous APIs by using the support libraries.

Comment: It is, but you should remove the `android:` prefix, so it will use support library resources instead of default Android: `background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`